# Get new value in edit box after N seconds without button in android

Tags: android

I am new in android and so, I need your help.

I want new and refreshed values in edit box such that after every 10 seconds without button click it brings changed value of PLC on edit box in my android device.

Comment: Show us what have you tried, your code.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
           edittext.settext(yourtext);
    }


 }, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a Timer for example. But think abaout, that this what You want to do is a Little bit battery intensive :

```
    //create a Timer and TimerTask
   private Timer timer;
   private YourTimerTask yourTimerTask;

   private void activateTimer(){

      if(timer!=null){
         timer.cancel();
         }

    timer = new Timer();
    yourTimerTask = new YourTimerTask();

    //this timer starts after 1 second and repeats every 10 seconds
    timer.schedule(yourTimerTask, 1000, 10000);

      }


     private class YourTimerTask extends TimerTask {

           @Override
             public void run() {

               runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {
                yourEditBox.setText(yourText);
                 }});
                }

            }
```

I think with Edit box You mean an EditText? Anyway, this example is not tested, just from scratch. But it should give You an idea how to do.